# How to random mixing string in Python3 code?

Tags: python-3.6

I'am beginner programmer in python3 code and have file.txt in format:

```
> 1.11слова1qwert
> 2.22Предложенный2fghjk
> 3.3текст434lkhh
> 4.798показанkjbhj
> 5.+_lкачества(7^#5
> 6.изучитьязыкQuestionsпрограммированияPython3
```

I want to writing python3 code, he is mixing strings in this file.txt. For example:

```
> 4.798показанkjbhj
> 1.11слова1qwert
> 5.+_lкачества(7^#5
> 2.22Предложенный2fghjk
> 6.изучитьязыкQuestionsпрограммированияPython3
> 3.3текст434lkhh
```

Please, help me, how to developing this code? What sort of python-method or python-function?

ps. Sorry for my bad English language

Comment: Use `readlines` to read lines into a list, `random.shuffle` to shuffle the list, iterate over the result and write to output file. Try to do it yourself, and ask if there are any *specific* problems you encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a random module which you can import.
i give you some hints:

- you have to read the lines of the data with `.readlines()`
- then mix it with `shuffle` method of random module
- after that you have to write the lines to "file.txt" (method:`.writelines()`)

Try to find out how to write the code by yourself. If you have any questions just ask.

Comment: Thanks so much, I try it